# Is it possible to use Linux/unix's dd to make an image backup of an android phone with the phone off?

Tags: backup, nexus-5

My current position:

Nexus 5
Unlocked with TWRP Recovery

I've been wanting to "rom hop" for a bit, but I'd like to have a good, solid foundation to return to in case of catastrophic failure.

If this were just a normal flash drive, on my computer I'd just

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdX of=~/my.img
```

However with a cell phone I'm not sure if it will work the same way.

I saw [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/86207/create-a-dd-image-of-a-android-4-4-4-for-forensics) answer linked while I typed this up, but it looks like the guy in that question specifically wants the `/data` partition (though he might not have known it at first).

tl;dr: How do I make a dd image of my android phone from my linux laptop?

Comment: Related: [Create a dd image of a Android 4.4.4 for forensics?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/86207/16575)

Comment: @Izzy I agree. That's why I linked it in the post

Comment: Yuck. Missed that. Just checked the ID in the link, which didn't match – as you linked to the answer directly... My bad, apologies. Shall we leave the comment in, or shall we "cleanup all these comments"?

Comment: BTW: The answer you've linked to matches your situation pretty well. I've just linked to the wrong post of mine – the one I had in mind was [this one](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/87726/16575) made by Joshua. Especially, check [this link from the comments](http://www.df.lth.se/~jokke/androidfilerecovery/) for a full guide. If that's an acceptable solution to you, I can post a summary as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access any filesystems over USB (or any other way) with the phone turned off. To make a full backup of user data and the ROM (system image), you need to boot into your custom recovery and [use that to make a Nandroid backup](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/47975/is-there-a-way-to-do-nandroid-backup-directly-to-pc-and-then-restore-it-directly).

Comment: First part is right (with the device turned off, no way). Second part is not the only solution, see [my answer here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/86211/16575) ;)